# How to zip a file in perl using IO::Compress::Zip

Tags: file, perl, zip

does anyone knows how to use the Level option in IO::Compress::Zip?

I have the problem that I am trying to zip a DB Backup file. But after Zip the file is smaller then the original file and cant be used to importing the file on another server. The file is corupt ore something like this...
I am using perl to zip the file like this...

```
my $zipfile = zip['MYFILE'] => $zipFile, Zip64 => 1, Method => ZIP_CM_STORE
        or die "Zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

But no Success. For example orig file size is 13.910.216KB and when Zipped its only 13.909.298KB.

I dont know why but i think i need to set the Level option to Z_NO_COMPRESSION. How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: `ZIP_CM_STORE` stores the file as it is (i.e. without compression) already. I think your problem is elsewhere, i.e. cannot be reproduced just by using the single line you show. Apart from that any compression used by zip is lossless, i.e. decompressing will resilt in exact the same data. Please provide enough context so that your problem can actually be reproduced - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi,
thats all I have. You dont need much more to reproduce this.Here is my full code...

`code`
sub NewZipFile()
 use IO::Compress::Zip qw(:all);
 my $zipFile = 'myzip.zip';

 my $s = zip [ 'PlaceABigFileHereAsExample'] => $zipFile, Zip64 => 1, Method => ZIP_CM_STORE
   or die "Zip failed: $ZipError\n";
}
`code`

After Zip, i use 7zip and just extract the file. And the size is different. Also it can not be used to import the file in my DB again...

Comment: This does not produce any problem for me. Where are you checking the size of the original and generated file? On the same machine or after you've transferred the data to some other machine - maybe with FTP and without binary mode?

Comment: Its everything on the same machine. Just after zipping the file.Just open the archive. You can also extract the file.

Comment: Again, this works perfectly for me. Please use `-s $filename` to get and print the size of the input and output files from inside the perl process which also does the zip.

Comment: I dont know, I will give it a try...
I have an orginal DB Backup file. And this file can be imported to the DB.Then i zip the file with the code above. Extract the file and try it to import. Manually. No scripts. And i get the error that de file is corrupt and the size is not as expected...

Comment: I just noted it works perfect for most of the files i tried. But Oracle .dmp file ist not working. The size is alway changed (smaller) than expected. Excel, Avi or what ever files are OK...

Comment: Are you sure that the files are not still written while you try to zip these? I.e. check the size before your zip and after the zip.

Comment: I've reread your question & now I'm unclear what you are doing. Using `ZIP_CM_STORE`  means no compression, so the resultant zip file should be bigger then the original file (because of the overhead of the zip container). You are reporting it smaller. That suggests a problem with writing the zip file. Try running `zip -t` against the zip file you've created to see if it is a valid zip file.

Comment: @pmqs The resultant ZIP file is bigger then the original file itself. But the zipped file inside the Zip is smaller then the original file.

Oracle Dump file for ex. is 3.450.508 KB
Zipped File is 3.451.025 KB
Extracted Oracle Dump file is 3.449.780KB

Comment: How did you check the size of the dump file stored in the zipfile? Did you unzip it and check the resultant size of the dump file wtitten to disk, or did you run `unzip -l` and check the size from the output? The answer will give us a pointer for where to look next.

Comment: I checked this multiple ways:

1. Extract zip file manually -> dmp file smaller
2. Extract with -l option -> dmp file smaller
3. Extract usin 7Zip -> dmp file smaller

:(

Comment: OK, that means the problem is likely to be how are using `IO::Compress::Zip`. What exactly is the input file `zip['MYFILE']` in your code? Is it a filename, a filehandle, or have you read the contents of the file into memory and are writing that to the zipfile?

Comment: Its a simple filename from my system...

Answer (score 2):

As has already been mentioned, by specifying the method `ZIP_CM_STORE` you are telling `IO::Compress::Zip` not to compress the file at all.

If you don't specify a `Method` at all, the code will use `ZIP_CM_DEFLATE` (which is the standard compression used in practically all zip files)

```
my $zipfile = zip['MYFILE'] => $zipFile, Zip64 => 1
        or die "Zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

If you want to change the compression level, use the `Level` option. By default it will uses `Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION` for the compression level. If you want the best compression, use `Z_BEST_COMPRESSION`

```
my $zipfile = zip['MYFILE'] => $zipFile, Zip64 => 1, Level => Z_BEST_COMPRESSION
        or die "Zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation thread I tried to reproduce the use-case.

First create a file similar in size to yours

```
$ truncate -s 13910K test
$ ls -lh test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxx yyy 14M Apr 13 12:00 test
```

Add it to zip file using `IO::Compress::Zip`

```
$ perl -MIO::Compress::Zip=:all -e 'zip "test" => "test.zip", Method => ZIP_CM_STORE'
```

Check the sizes & CRC

```
$ crc32 test
49769d91

$ ls -l test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxx yyy 14243840 Apr 13 12:00 test

$ unzip -lv test.zip 
Archive:  test.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
14243840  Stored 14243840   0% 2020-04-13 11:48 49769d91  test
--------          -------  ---                            -------
14243840         14243840   0%                            1 file
```

All is as expected. The sizes & CRCs match.

Could you try this on your system please?